# importdata cuts off data in the last 40-30 rows of multi-format csv

Tags: matlab, csv

I try to use 'importdata' to read in multiple-format csv files from multiple subfolders by using a loop. I noticed that the important piece of data at the last 30 rows is being cut off. Why does it happen?

I guess it could be that this part of CSV file has different number of columns. For example, rows 1 to 195 have 5 columns, then rows 196 to 233 have 9 columns. The data has text, decimals, integer formats.

My code looks like this:

```
 tic;

[P,F] = subdir('results');
filesPath = P;
files = F;
file_num = length(files);

x = [1:3:file_num-2]; % delete indicative names directories as it is not used
filesPath(x) = [];
files(x) = [];

nfilesleft = length(filesPath);
startFolder = pwd; 

% 'for loop' to extract 2 data fields by an indicative name
for k = 1:nfilesleft
    cd(filesPath{k})
    pwd    
    filesExtract = files{k};
        numFiles = numel(filesExtract);    
    for i = 1:numFiles 
        %[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(filesExtract{i})
        Input{i,k} = importdata(filesExtract{i});  
    end    
   cd(startFolder); % go back to the starting directory
end

toc;
```

Can anybody sugest a better way of reading multiple-format csv files for further analysis where you have to track down some type of data and using indices to plot it or do anything else.

Thank you!

Comment: You should add tag for your language/application.

Comment: Sorry,Leonid V, I am new to this. What do you mean in particular?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: This is written in MATLAB. Thanks! Corrected it.

Comment: Ok, found this answer: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/123150. It seems to work alrigt.